# Find a character and a new line, and keep them in previous line In VBA

Tags: regex, excel, vba

Suppose we've a condition like below:

```
"A","B","C","D", n
n
 E n
n
 F n
n
  n
n
 G n
n
```

We want to replace all the n which has a space before them and a new line after them with ""

Expected:

```
"A","B","C","D", EFG
```

I'm using below pattern to find but it's not able to find the "n"s in a .txt file.

Input

```
"A","B","C","D", n
n
```

Code used

```
   With RegEx
      .Pattern = "(^|\s)n[\n]"
      .Global = True
      .IgnoreCase = False
      .MultiLine = True
    End With

Debug.Print (RegEx.Test(strLine(LineIndex))) 'Output - False
```

Comment: Can you please include a [mcve] how you determine that nothing is found? The example in incomplete, and the pattern should somehow work as you can see here: https://regex101.com/r/SQOcV9/1

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
(?:^|[^\S\n]*)n(?:[^\S\n]*\n\s*|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WdjpUO/3)

Make sure to use `.MultiLine = False`.

**Pattern details**

- `(?:^|[^\S\n]*)` - either start of string or any 0 or more chars other than non-whitespace and newline
- `n` - an `n` char
- `(?:[^\S\n]*\n\s*|$)` - either

  - `[^\S\n]*\n\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces other than newline, then a newline and then 0+ whitespaces
  - `|` - or
  - `$` - end of string.

Comment: Well this is able to remove all the "n"s but it not able to bring the E F G to the previous line

Comment: @AbhinavKushagra If you have seen my demo, you can see it does. Share your input as a string literal if it does not for you. [Here is another demo](https://regex101.com/r/WdjpUO/4) with the `"A","B","C","D", n
n` as input.

Comment: @AbhinavKushagra If your line endings are CR, simply replace `\n` with `\r`: `(?:^|[^\S\r]*)n(?:[^\S\r]*\r\s*|$)`. Or a more generic: `(?:^|[^\S\r\n]*)\r?n(?:[^\S\r\n]*\r?\n\s*|$)`